# ADMIN LTE Notification dropdown not wrapping content

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, meteor-blaze, adminlte

**Notification Image:**

[image: Notification Bar]

From above Image it is clear that the Notification panel is not wrapping the content of the `message`. the actual text inside content is long, which is

`saurabh raised first
 request to review Task 
 'ABCDE NOV 2017'
 with Assignment ID 'Qg9hBNSTozkExpTYn'`

Below is the code that I am using to show notification.

```
<li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="notificationLink" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <ul class="menu">
                {{#each notifications}}
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">
                            <small><strong>{{title}}</strong></small>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <small style="pull-right">
                                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{createdAt}}
                                </small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row pull-left">
                                <p>{{message}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**Any Idea How to wrap the text?**

> You can view page [here](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html)

Comment: Perhaps, you could show jsfiddle with working example?

Comment: @styx: You can simply click here https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to fix that:

```
.notifications-menu .menu > li a p {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

CSS selector has been adjusted for the html code you've shown.

Answer (score 2):

Admin lte by default uses

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

and

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

so notification text will be like that when it's long

[image]

if you want to show the full text in all dropdown use

```
.navbar-nav>.notifications-menu>.dropdown-menu>li .menu>li>a, .navbar-nav>.messages-menu>.dropdown-menu>li .menu>li>a, .navbar-nav>.tasks-menu>.dropdown-menu>li .menu>li>a {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

for the code you provided use

```
.notifications-menu>.dropdown-menu>li .menu>li>a p {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS selector won't work, because HTML layout is different from AdminLTE's one.

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
.menu {
  word-wrap : break-word;
}
```